# .NET 6 Linux Self-Contained Exit Code 133

Tags: php, .net, linux

Why when executed on Linux would this self-contained, linux-x64, single file app produce return code 133? This is on shared hosting.

C# App

```
public class Program {
    public static int Main(string[] args) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Executing via PHP

```
exec('./app', $output, $retval);
echo 'Returned with status $retval and output:\n';
print_r($output);
```

Output

```
Returned with status 133 and output: Array ( )
```

Comment: Is the app actually executed? Did you check the value returned by `exec()`?

Comment: @Olivier the return value is 133. I should note I'm able to exec things like 'ls'.

Comment: I was not referring to `$retval`. If you write `$res = exec(...);`, is `$res` equal to `false` or an empty string?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, but 133 usually means your program got a SIGTRAP. How do you compile it?

Comment: The app you compiled was probably compiled dynamically. Run `ldd ./app` to check the links, the hosting environment is probably missing the required libraries, like `dotnet-runtime-8.0` or whatever. Also, shared hosting environments don't usually allow running binaries, as it's a security risk.